# Core Data fetch returning an empty array, but debugging shows that SQLite rows are returned?

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite, core-data

I have a One to Many relationship between Routes and Trips in Core Data (Every trip must follow a route, but there can be many trips on the same route). There are 40 routes and a few thousand trips.

At this point the routes have already been inserted and the context saved, and now I am trying to fetch the routes, based on id, so that I can link them to the trips.

```
for trip in trips {
        let id = Int(trip[0]) ?? 0
        let direction = Int(trip[1]) ?? 0
        let routeId = trip[2]

        let newTrip = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Trip", into: context)
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Route")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", routeId)
        do {
            let routes = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)  // 1
            print("\(routes.count) routes")               // 2
            let route = routes[0] as! NSManagedObject
            newTrip.setValue(id, forKey: "id")
            newTrip.setValue(direction, forKey: "direction")
            newTrip.setValue(route, forKey: "route")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

The first time through the loop is fine, but on the second time through I get some weird behavior. I have debugging enabled for core data, and lines 1 and 2 print the following in the console:

```
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0026s for 1 rows.
0 routes
```

So the SQLite Query is returning 1 row, but when I try to access it through core data it's not there, so then my app crashes. Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Your app crashes because you are trying to unwrap nonexistent value for 
let route = routes[0] as! NSManagedObject. Use if let route = routes.first as? NSManagedObject. At least your app won't crash anymore. Also you should check the routeId. Are you sure that the value is the same as your existed route.id in your DB?

Comment: I know why it crashes, but it shouldn't be nil and if it is nothing else is going to work, so for now I want it to crash. The route id is the same on the first and second iterations through the loop, and in the console I can see that it is finding the proper route right before it crashes

Comment: One explanation would be that the `route` fetched has been deleted in the context (but that deletion has not yet been saved to the store).

Comment: I never figured out what was wrong, but I rewrote that part of my program (with what seemed like basically the same code) and then it worked fine.